# jqplot remove half dot circle when value is zero instead of full dot circle

Tags: jqplot

I already read the api documentation from top to bottom many times already, searching for a solution to make a full dot instead of a half dot when the value is zero. To get the picture right this is my sample. I have been trying many ways to force it to full dot circle, but no luck. Thank you for the help. :D

[image: dot problem]

Comment: I think it's the usual behaviour as a dot is displayed around a particular value (if value is equals to 0, it is displayed from -0.1 to 0.1 for example). As your yaxis begins at 0 it can only display a half dot circle. You can try to force zIndex value of your dots (use Firebug to find corresponding class), or specify a yaxis starting at -1 for example

Comment: no luck bro, I actually tried moving those lines already and z-indexed it, its pure half circle when value is zero. It's how the plugin works, just half dot when zero :'(

Comment: Oh okay I thought it was just a question of CSS

Answer (score 0):

Using another plugin was no option for me since that will require more time, and time is really really important to me right now cause I am already lacking on it. Well basically my solution was a cheat way or basically a noob way. I actually used two divs, then just combine those two, the first graph only has the bar graph, and the 2nd graph only contains the two line graphs. I basically modified it using css to merge the two graphs, hide some of the unwanted axis, ticks and stuffs from one graph and then I get this result

[image]

Comment: can you please share the code.... nice approach by the way.
I am not sure whether this would be good way of doing it in a long run.